accessing services running in docker via http request in python code
I am developing a small rag application using docker compose, and there are three services     chromadb (vector database) for store embedding, ollama for running llm and python application.
and i tired  to access the chroma services from python code via
import ollama, sys, chromadb
chroma = chromadb.HttpClient(host="http:/0.0.0.0, port=8000)


it gives me that error
ragapp          |   File "/ragapp/./search.py", line 6, in <module>
ragapp          |     chroma = chromadb.HttpClient(host="http://0.0.0.0", port=8000)
ragapp          |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ragapp          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 197, in HttpClient
ragapp          |     return ClientCreator(tenant=tenant, database=database, settings=settings)
ragapp          |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ragapp          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 144, in __init__
ragapp          |     self._validate_tenant_database(tenant=tenant, database=database)
ragapp          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 440, in _validate_tenant_database
ragapp          |     raise ValueError(
ragapp          | ValueError: Could not connect to a Chroma server. Are you sure it is running?


and i tired to specify hostname for chromadb and ollama  in docker compose file  as following
version: '3.1'
services:
  ollama:
    image: ollama/ollama
    hostname: ollama
    volumes:
      - ./data/ollama:/root/.ollama
    ports:
      - "11434:11434"

  chromadb:
    image: chromadb/chroma
    hostname: chroma
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
  ragapp:
    container_name: ragapp
    image: ragapp
    depends_on:
      - ollama
      - chromadb


Note Both of ollama and chromadb services are running  http://0.0.0.0:11434 and http://0.0.0.0:8000
So how could i access those service in python app service.

When binding to a port 0.0.0.0 tells ot to listen on all network interfaces. You can't use that to connect from anywhere. Try using the services name instead in your python app. http://chromadb:8000
